# Visual Studio 2012 error C2039: 'serialize' : is not a member of 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty>'

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2012, shared-ptr

I am stuck with this problem while compiling my static class library.

I know that Boost doesn't officially support VS2012 but since this is my current development environment, I could really use some advice.

I have been searching around but nothing so far has helped me.

Sample code:

Foo.h:

```
#include "FooImpl.h"
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(void) : pImpl(std::make_shared<FooImpl>()) {}
    //similar constructors follow

    //a few get methods here
private:
    std::shared_ptr<FooImpl> pImpl;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int file_version);
}
```

Foo.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Foo.h"

template<class Archive>
void Foo::serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int ver) 
{  
    ar & pImpl;
}

template void Foo::serialize<boost::archive::text_iarchive>(
    boost::archive::text_iarchive & ar, 
    const unsigned int file_version
);
template void Foo::serialize<boost::archive::text_oarchive>(
    boost::archive::text_oarchive & ar, 
    const unsigned int file_version
);
```

FooImpl.h:

```
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>

class FooImpl
{
public:
    FooImpl(void);
    //other constructors, get methods

private:
    //data members - unsigned int & std::wstring

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int ver);
};
```

FooImpl.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "FooImpl.h"

//function implementations

template <typename Archive>
void FooImpl::serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int ver)
{
    ar & id_;
    ar & code_;
}

//Later added, serialization requires these

template void FooImpl::serialize<boost::archive::text_iarchive>(
    boost::archive::text_iarchive & ar, 
    const unsigned int file_version
);

template void FooImpl::serialize<boost::archive::text_oarchive>(
    boost::archive::text_oarchive & ar, 
    const unsigned int file_version
);
```

Comment: What line of code gives the error? Also, shouldn't `ar & pImpl;` be `ar & (*pImpl);`? (pImpl is a pointer.)

Comment: @David Schwartz
It compiles now but it seems this is not the solution.
Whenever I try to serialize a shared_ptr holding the foo in my main method, I get the same error there.

Comment: What do you mean by the "same error"? The error you described is a compiler error and you say it compiles now.

Comment: I use the static library in another project, which won't compile trying to serialize the shared pointer.

Comment: Can you paste the code that doesn't compile?

Comment: `std::stringstream ss;

    const shared_ptr<Foo> foo;
    {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ss);
        oa << foo;
    }
    shared_ptr<Foo> foo1;
    {
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ss);
        ia >> foo1;
    }`

Comment: `oa << foo;` should be `oa << (*foo);`. You want to serialize the object the pointer points to, not the pointer itself. (Serializing a pointer doesn't really make any logical sense.)

Comment: Ow, made the same mistake the second time there. It works fine now.

Can you make it an answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to serialize pointers. You want to serialize the thing the pointer points to. The simplest way is to replace `foo << ptr;` with `foo << (*ptr);`.

The parentheses around `*ptr` are not necessary and many would see them as a sign of clumsiness. But if you find they make things clearer for you, use them.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of the boost serialization library that it *can* serialize pointers intelligently? Otherwise what is the point of `boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp`?

Answer (score 1):

`boost::serialization` is an extensible that can extended to work with any types, so you can implement your own version of `load/save` for `std::shared_ptr`, take a look at `boost_installation_path/boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp` and implement your own `load/save` from it. As another workaround you can use `boost::shared_ptr` in place of `std::shared_ptr`!! since you are using `boost` I see no advantage of using `std::shared_ptr` over `boost::shared_ptr`