# How do I make boost::serialization work with std::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

This question has been [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835780/visual-studio-2012-error-c2039-serialize-is-not-a-member-of-stdshared-pt) and a few other places but the answers don't really seem to address the latest Boost library.

To illustrate the issue, suppose we want to serialize a class containing a shared pointer (`std::shared_ptr`), along with a static `load` function that will build the class from a file and a `save` function that will store the instance to a file:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>

#include <fstream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class A
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<int> v;

    void A::Save(char * const filename);
    static A * const Load(char * const filename);

        //////////////////////////////////
        // Boost Serialization:
        //
    private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int file_version) 
        {
            ar & v;
        }
};

// save the world to a file:
void A::Save(char * const filename)
{
    // create and open a character archive for output
    std::ofstream ofs(filename);

    // save data to archive
    {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);

        // write the pointer to file
        oa << this;
    }
}

// load world from file
A * const A::Load(char * const filename)
{
    A * a;

    // create and open an archive for input
    std::ifstream ifs(filename);

    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);

    // read class pointer from archive
    ia >> a;

    return a;
}

int main()
{

}
```

The above code generates a long list of errors starting with `c:\local\boost_1_54_0\boost\serialization\access.hpp(118): error C2039: 'serialize' : is not a member of 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty>'`, which as far as I understand shouldn't be true given that I have loaded the boost `shared_ptr` serialization library which ostensibly supports `std::shared_ptr`. What am I missing here?

**NOTE: As far as I understand, my assumption that `boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp` defined a `serialize` function for `std::shared_ptr` was wrong, hence the correct answer to this question is probably that I'd either have to define my own `serialize` functions for `std::shared_ptr` or convert to `boost::shared_ptr`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, std::shared_ptr and boost::shared_ptr are unrelated class templates.

`Boost.Serizalization` doesn't support `std::shared_ptr` out of the box, but you can add such a support in your application - just take a look at `<boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>` header.

Comment: I am aware of that; it's the basis for my question.

Comment: @ausairman Then your question is unclear. You state that "Boost 1.54, <...> is supposed to support std::shared_ptr" - which is incorrect.

Comment: Ok. I have now explicitly stated that I am attempting to use the `boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp` header.

Comment: Also, my understanding is that it *does* support `std::shared_ptr`; why else would it ship with a header that defines serialization methods for it?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood the use of that library and your answer. Are you saying that the `boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp` header is *not* a serialization for `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: @ausairman Correct. `boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp` implements non-intrusive serialization for `boost::shared_ptr`. There's no support for `std::shared_ptr`, but one can implement it for his own needs, it's quite simple.

Answer (score 2):

**This is the best answer I have been able to come up with myself. If someone has something better to say on this I will accept that as an answer instead.**

The `boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp` header that boost ships with *is not* support for `std::shared_ptr` but for `boost::shared_ptr`. If you want to make serialization work with shared pointer objects *without* bootlegging your own serialization code then you will need to convert your `std::shared_ptr` objects to `boost::shared_ptr` objects and [live with the consequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902313/difference-between-boostshared-ptr-and-stdshared-ptr-from-the-standard-memo).

My misunderstanding was that I thought that `boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp` defined a `serialize` method for `std::shared_ptr`. I was wrong.

Comment: Conversion from `std::shared_ptr` to `boost::shared_ptr` I've seen stores as a destructor a mutable lambda that captures by value `std::shared_ptr`. So if you want to serialize that kind of structure, you would still need a way to serialize the destructor, and, hence the `std::shared_ptr`. So its the chicken and eggs problem. Are you aware of other conversions that do it differently?